# How to write Replace root and merge objects aggregation operation in spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework

I have written a MongoDB native query which is working as expected. I'm trying to write its Spring data equivalent query but unable to do so. Basically, I wanted to filter out array of fields on the basis of titles provided in input array. Here is the sample document:

```
{
   "domain":"diageotest.com",
   "locale":"en-gb",
   "pageName":"Content_1",
   "contents":[
      {
         "contentName":"Template_1",
         "fields":[
            {

               "id":"firstname",
               "fieldType":"Plain Text",
               "title":"First Name",
               "value":"Pawan"
            },
            {             
               "id":"lastname",
               "fieldType":"Plain Text",
               "title":"Last Name",
               "value":"Kumar"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "createdBy":"ag-KumarJog",
   "createdDate":"Jan 23,2019",
   "isDefaultLocale":true,
   "modifiedBy":"ag-KumarJog",
   "modifiedDate":"Jan 23,2019",
   "version":1
}
```

And below is my native query:

```
db.contents.aggregate([ 
                {$match: { $and: [
                                {"domain": "diageotest.com"},
                                {"locale": {$in: ["en-in", "en-us"]}},
                                {"contents.contentName": "Template_1"}
                                ]
                                                }
                }, 
                {$unwind: "$contents"}, 
                {$unwind: "$contents.fields"}, 
                {$match: { "contents.fields.title": {$in: ["First Name"]}}}, 
                {$group: { "_id": "$_id", 
                           "contents":  { "$push": "$contents"}, 
                           "root": {$first:"$$ROOT"} }}, 
                {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:{$mergeObjects:["$root",{contents:'$contents'}]}}},
                {$skip : 0},
                {$limit : 5}
                ]);
```

Here, in above query, if I pass "First Name" in array ($in condition), then the output JSON will contain only that field whose title is "First Name".

In java, I was trying below but got stuck at replace root:

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = this.matchByTemplateDomainAndLocales(domainName, templateName,
                requestBody.getLocales());
// ---------------------------------------------------//
UnwindOperation unwindContents = unwind("$contents");
UnwindOperation unwindFields = unwind("$contents.fields");
MatchOperation matchFields = match(where("contents.fields.title").in(requestBody.getFields()));
GroupOperation groupOperation = group("id").push("$contents").as("contents").first("$$ROOT").as("root");
//ReplaceRootOperation replaceRootOperation = builder().withDocument()
// ---------------------------------------------------//
SortOperation sortOperation = sort(sort);
LimitOperation limitOperation = limit(requestBody.getLimit());
SkipOperation skipOperation = skip(requestBody.getSkip().longValue());
```

I'm not able to find appropriate methods in replace root that accepts array and perform merge. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the 'contents' field name you could go with:

```java
ReplaceRootOperation operation = replaceRoot().withValueOf(ObjectOperators.valueOf("$root").mergeWith("$content"));
```

Otherwise, not sure if this would be the cleanest solution but you can create it as such:

```java
Map<String, String> fieldMapping = new HashMap<>();
fieldMapping.put("content", "$content");
ReplaceRootOperation operation = replaceRoot().withValueOf(ObjectOperators.valueOf("$root").mergeWith(fieldMapping));
```

Comment: **Pedro**, Thanks for giving your time. I tried your solution but its giving me an error : `Command failed with error 40400 (Location40400): '$mergeObjects requires object inputs, but input [....]`  Could you please guide me on this. The problem is $contents is an array. So I'm not able to find method supporting this.

Comment: Use 'mergeWithValuesOf' instead of 'mergeWith' to not throw a  40400 error